# Will a new immigrant be allowed entry in the USA if he hasn't yet payed the USCIS Immigrant Fee?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, fees-and-charges

People who obtain a US Immigrant Visa are required to pay a "USCIS Immigrant Fee", for Green Card processing. The official instructions recommend to pay this fee before entry to the US, so that you receive the GC in minimum time. **They also mention it's possible to pay it after entering the US.**

**Could someone with a valid visa, who hasn't yet payed this fee, be denied to board on the flight to US, when going through security airport?**

Comment: Would you tell us which valid visa the person currently holds?

Comment: This question should probably be in the Expatriates Stack Exchange, as it is not about travel, but immigration.

Comment: It's DV1(Diversity Visa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they will be allowed entry, and they will become a permanent resident immediately upon entry as usual. They just won't be mailed the physical plastic green card. However, their immigrant visa, endorsed upon entry, serves as a green card for one year, so they will still be able to prove their permanent resident status without the plastic card in the short term.